# Button to turn on/off DESC ordering

Tags: php

I'm really sorry if there is something about this already, but I was not able to find it.
I really hope you will understand me and my silly problem.

I'm inserting datas from MySQL database table into my pages using `$query_sel = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $id $DESCswitch";` and I want to let people change the ordering way by clicking on button. Sometimes they just want to order from lowest to highest and sometimes they want order from highest to lowest.

I want to make a button (no form with radio buttons or checkbox, just button) and using this button change the `$DESCswitch` variable from " " to "DESC" and back using still the same button.

I know there have to be something like `$DESCswitch = $_POST['DESCswitch'];` before that `$query_sel = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY $id $DESCswitch";`, but I have no idea how to get something into the POST without using form.

I know I have not explained it very well, but can anybody help me?

note: The page can be reloaded after pressing that button, but I cannot use GET method due to security reasons and that's why I exactly use POST method.

Comment: POST is absolutely no more secure than GET.  This will require a form, but it doesn't have to look like a form.

Comment: What's the problem sir? you have two ways here: 1) prepare a form with a button that, on submit, will set the $DESCswitch to ASC or DESC. 2) use a button and, through AJAX, execute a query and reload the table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski GET is not good for me because some people may try to change it their own way (in address bar and that's what I don't want)

Comment: But they can just as easily craft a fake post request. Not as simply as via the address bar,  but trivially nonetheless. Just know that get, post, and cookies are all equally insecure.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like that.

```
<form method="POST"><button type="submit" name="DESCSWITCH" value="DESC">DESC</button></form>
<form method="POST"><button type="submit" name="DESCSWITCH" value="ASC">ASC</button></form>
```

Don't forget to check the value of the field to prevent SQL injections.

```
<?php
if (!in_array($_POST['DESCSWITCH'], array('ASC','DESC')))
  $_POST['DESCSWITCH'] = 'DESC';
```

Comment: @briosheje action is by default the current page